# Search for files and print their full path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, grep

`ls -R /media/X | grep filename` lets me search for file names, but it only prints the file name and not the directory it resides in. How can I print the file name *and* its directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) for these purposes.

Try

```
find /media/X | grep filename
```

You can achieve the same results without `grep` (as @geekosaur points out), but `find`'s syntax can be hassle if you're already used to `grep`.

Comment: it's preferred with `grep` as names are highlighted ^_^

Comment: @wisdom: Still, `find /media/X -name '*filename*' | grep filename` would be quicker (how much depends on how many files there are) _and_ highlight the output. And you will get the warm fuzzy feeling of using the right tools for the job :-) .

Answer (score 5):

`ls` and `grep` aren't really the right tools for that; you want the `find` command.

```
find /media/X -name '*filename*'
```

This also lets you look for other conditions such as by age.

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer from @Dennis will consume a vast amount of CPU and/or IO if there are a lot of files under `/media/X` since *find* will recursively list **everything** under the defined path unless some limiting flags are used. In the average case this may not matter, but deep recursion followed by grepping an excessively long list is certainly not optimal.

You will generally get faster results using the *locate* command (e.g. from the *mlocate* package). For example:

```
$ locate virtualbox/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/virtualbox/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/virtualbox/README.Debian.html
```

The main limitation of this approach is that the various *locate* packages generally will not index private home directories under ecryptfs, which may be a concern for Ubuntu users. Since the OP is using Ubuntu, I'd recommend using *locate* for system files, and *find* with some sensible limiting flags for anything stored within an ecryptfs mount.

Lastly, it's worth mentioning that using *find* without an absolute path as the starting point may not do what the OP wants anyway. The original question was how to return a filename along with its path, so unless a relative path is acceptable, *locate* is again more likely to return the proper result.

Comment: I just want to add that the amount of time it takes to traverse a directory tree in this way depends heavily on the underlying filesystem.

Comment: Thanks alot for your great answer as it's fastest !...but how about locating under /media/ path ? how do I do that ? seems I can't !

Comment: @wisdom *mlocate* will prune /media by default. If you want to index removable media, you can edit PRUNEPATHS in `/etc/updatedb.conf` to suit yourself. If you remove the entry for /media, it will be included in the index the next time *updatedb* is run. Also note that your *locate* results may be out of date, since the index is only as current as the last invocation of *updatedb*, which is why /media is excluded by default.

Comment: @CodeGnome that's great ! Wow....but still can't find files in my `/media/` even it's included ! why ? I do `mlocate -b 'fedora'` but can't find it in my `/media/`